# macOS sets wrong time/date multiple times a day

Tags: time

I've been running High Sierra since october 2017 and kept it until a few weeks ago.
Since then, my computer was reverting back several times a day its date/time to 5th of December 2013 9pm_something (I could notice it easily as Night Shift was enabled) then reverted back to sync time less than 15 seconds after.

I never really tried to find where it came from, as it was not a very big problem.

But, I recently jumped from High Sierra to Big Sur and the problem got worse. The system still reverts back to 5th of December 2013 but doesn't update to sync time right after (like it did with High Sierra), unless I open the Preferences and unlock the date/time panel...

So, must come from some fancy addon I once added to my system, but I honestly have no idea where to start looking for.

Thanks to whoever can help me and sorry for my funny English.

Comment: Which specific Mac model are you using?

Comment: iMac18,3 (iMac 5k, mid-2017)

Comment: Does this still happen if you disable **”Set date and time automatically”** in the *Date & Time* system preference pane?

Comment: Sadly yes. I thought it was coming from there

Comment: Does it happen if you run in Safe Mode (hold ‘Shift’ during boot)?

Comment: Well, since I'm teleworking on this computer right now, leaving it in safe mode for a whole day would be a problem for me.

Comment: If you can try this on a day off of work, it would help us narrow down the root cause.